Is it possible to have an ElevatedButton execute more than one action?
I have a standard ElevatedButton action:
                    ElevatedButton(
                      onPressed: () => myPolicySet.serialize(),
                      child: const Text('serialize'),
                    ),

I also want it to navigate to a new page:
                    ElevatedButton(
                      onPressed: () {
                        Navigator.push(
                          context,
                          MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => const DiagramAppTwo()),
                      },
                      child: const Text('serialize'),
                    ),

Is this possible? if so, how should I do it?

onPressed: () { Action1(); ActionB();}

Thanks: figured it had to be something simple (too simple to show up in the documentation!).

Can't you make a separate function and pass to onPressed?? And in that function you can write the code for both.

Maybe.
I like the simple solution up above.

you're free to setup a how much actions you want
like: onPressed: () { FirstAction(); SecondAction();}
in your example,it should be :
        ElevatedButton(
                          onPressed: () {
                           myPolicySet.serialize();
                            Navigator.push(
                              context,
                              MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => const DiagramAppTwo());
                          },
                          child: const Text('serialize'),
                        ),


Yeah, that's what I ended up with!
Thanks!

awesome,set the answer you ended up with as correct,so other people can see the solution easily

This is what I ended up with:
        ElevatedButton(
                          onPressed: () {
                           myPolicySet.serialize();
                            Navigator.push(
                              context,
                              MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => const DiagramAppTwo());
                          },

                          child: const Text('serialize'),
                        ),>

